# very simple highcharts column graph with two arrays

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a simple highcharts column graph.  The documentation on the highcharts website is more complex than I need and I just can't figure out how to use a simple array for the y axis.  This is my code so far.

```
var species=[Acer rubrum,Tsuga canadensis,Pinus strobus];
var counts=[17746,10384,9986];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Top 10 Species'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'by basal area'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: species,
    title: {
      text: 'Species'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0

  },


  series: [{ name: null, data: topSpecies }]
});
}
```

This gives me the correct species listed along the x-axis, but I want the counts along the y and currently it is blank and there are no columns.  Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong variable for series data. Use `counts` instead of `topSpecies`.

```
var species = ['Acer rubrum', 'Tsuga canadensis', 'Pinus strobus'];
var counts = [17746, 10384, 9986];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        name: null,
        data: counts
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yfesv93x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Thanks!  That was actually a typo from when I made the question here.  I figured out the real issue was that I had strings instead of numbers in my counts array.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you haven't assigned your Y-axis any categories.

```
yAxis: {
categories: counts,
```

},

see the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/odrga0hL/3/